# Como organizar muitas divs no Bootstrap (Imagem)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, div

Como faço para organizar muitas divs col-xx-3 de **alturas diferentes**?
Existe alguma classe ou algum outro metodo sem usar row (a cada 4 produtos)?
Alguma forma que *não precise mudar o Select ou o PHP*?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de várias formas porém não consegui. Tentei mudar o Select já, e o PHP também, porém sempre caí em algum problema bem maior.

Lembrando que não tenho muita prática. Estou aberto a qualquer ideia!

Agradeço a todos!

*(algumas coisas no layout ainda vão mudar, a imagem é só de demostração)*

Comment: Não entendi muito bem como você quer essa organização. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: me desculpe pela confusão, mas pode ver na imagem que as divs estão desorganizadas, queria algo alinhado superior, sem esse espaço em branco ao lado esquerdo (por exemplo). @Randrade

Comment: Então, existem sites que buscam essa "desorganização" de tamanhos como requisito de layout. No seu caso, você quer que fique colado uma na outra e com um tamanho fixo? E o texto, tem problema cortar ou irá adicionar um espaço em branco nos que não possuírem texto suficiente?

Comment: Sim, eu já vi esses layouts 'desorganizados', porem nesse caso, imagino, que é melhor manter uma organização mais severa, (devido ao publico alvo e outras questões). Assim, planejava manter as imagens e titulos alinhados, e se sobrasse espaços abaixo entre um produto e outro seria melhor que espaços de produtos "faltando" como está acontecendo. @Randrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, sobre a margem entre as div's, basta alterar o `CSS` em sua página, alterando a margem.

```
.col-md-3{
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Em relação ao tamanho, creio que você não saiba o tamanho de cada texto para definir o `min-heigth` da página, então aconselho utilizar `jQuery` para obter o maior tamanho de cada `div` e setar o `heigth` igual para todas.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.col-md-3').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.col-md-3').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

Veja um exemplo funcionado no [JsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fsxt4rmw/1/)

Referências: [Use jQuery/CSS to find the tallest of all elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781074/4843158)

Se quiser alterar o tamanho por blocos, pode separar o valor do `maxHeigth` em cada bloco, desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

      $('.row').each(function() {

       $(this).find('.col-md-3').each(function() {
         maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
       });

       $(this).find('.col-md-3').each(function() {
         $(this).height(maxHeight);
       });

   });
 });
```

Exemplo funcional no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsxt4rmw/2/).

Comment: Apenas lembrando, o bootstrap ajuda muito no desenvolvimento, mas ele não resolve todos os nossos problemas. 
O que você deseja seria melhor se você mesmo fizesse um `CSS` de acordo com a sua necessidade, onde teria blocos para cada tamanho, e na criação do produto setaria qual o tamanho precisaria. Isso daria uma melhor organização em sua tela, da forma que deseja.

Comment: Sim, bootstrap é muito bom, mas sempre acabo mudando muita coisa, além de criar um extenso CSS para atender o que preciso. Eu entendi a sua ideia, mas tem um caso que a maior col-xx-3 é muito grande, e acaba desconfigurando todo o resto da pagina com espaços muito grandes, teria como ajustar isso?

Comment: Mas no caso o que você quer que seja feito em relação a isso? Você disse que não teria problemas em deixar um espaço no fim. Você quer que corte ou o que?

Comment: A questão mesmo, é que o espaço maior não ficou somente embaixo dos 'vizinhos' do maior, mas sim de todos, e acaba que linhas, com 1 produto ou alturas pequenas ficam com espaços muito grandes, entende? Eu terei de ver como exatamente ficaria essa organização, se fosse possível adicionar a maior altura de cada linha seria o ideal, eu imagino, mas não sei ao certo e nem executar.

Comment: @Lucas Nesse caso você pode fazer por blocos, ao invés de fazer em tudo.

Comment: @Lucas Editei a resposta. Não está bonito, mas estou sem tempo para fazer da melhor forma agora. Mas dessa forma irá funcionar da forma que você precisa.

Comment: Apesar de não ser o totalmente certo, vou aplicar a primeira maneira que você apresentou, pois tive poucas exceções, é preferível alterar as informações no que alterar grande parte do código. (ainda estou analisando a segunda maneira). Muito obrigado pela ajuda, tempo e paciência!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir uma altura fixa máxima para os elementos, no seu caso ai, os itens estão aglomerando pois tem uns com altura maior que o outro. Se colocar a altura das class="col-sm-3" nesse caso ai em 200px por exemplo por padrão, resolverá o problema!

Comment: Eu tentei realizar dessa maneira. Desse jeito algumas divs se sobrepõem às outras de baixo, e ainda ficam alguns espaços em branco (como na imagem)

Comment: Está online? Pode passar o link para dar uma olhada??

Comment: Coloquei online aqui, está como exemplo 300px, mas se vc inspecionar e mudar dará pra ver melhor: [link](http://pennarepresentacoes.com.br/beta/fabrica.php?id=36&nome=MaxAuto)

Comment: Para mi aqui apareceu normal, tudo certinho, sem espaços em brancos.

Comment: Eu fiz algumas correções e fixei um tamanho médio, mas terei que alterar alguns registros e limitar o tamanho dos textos para não haver muita variação

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer um PHP, criando uma soma antes de listar cada lista, se a soma for = 4 que é a quantidade de Li por linha, joga uma div clearfix e zera a soma para efetuar novamente, outra dica é utilizar o mansory, já ouviu falar? segue alguns links, ele ajusta as Li: 
http://masonry.desandro.com/
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Caso queira seguir o exemplo em php, jogue o código no plunker que lhe ajudo!

Comment: Tentei utilizar 'clearfix' nas divs mas não fez diferença, todos os thumb já estão em class="box clearfix".
Eu gostei da ideia do masony, vou tentar usar aqui e se tiver alguma duvida comentarei aqui :)

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é com a classe "row"

Comment: Sim, mas no caso da classe row eu teria que mudar muita coisa no PHP, e isso ja começa a complicar bem mais. Mas se eu não consguir uma solução terei que arrumar uma maneira de usar row.