# Empilhar Blocos com Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estou fazendo um layout usando bootstrap e me deparei com um problema na hora de empilhar blocos para ser responsivo.

Tenho 5 blocos de alturas diferentes, divididos em 3 colunas:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao chegar em certa largura preciso que os blocos se empilhem, mas a altura de cada "camada" é definida pelo maior bloco dela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém teria uma solução para isso?

Comment: O que deseja seria algo parecido [com essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124234/20615)?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, tem uma solução, porém para obter o efeito desejado, você terá que usar um plugin chamado masonry.

De um estudada, é bem prático.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Seria mais ou menos assim, as grid item seriam suas li. 
Este plugin faz com que de acordo com a resolução da sua tela ele se adapte e deixe de forma responsiva automaticamente.