# Div Preencher espaço em branco

Tags: html, css, materialize

Olá,estou precisando de um help para alinhar div.

Como podem ver na imagem:
[image: IMG]

A div não ocupa este espaço em branco,porém queria que ela ocupasse este espaço,que nem a div de cima fica do lado de outra.

As tabelas estão destribuidas desta forma:
[image: IMG2]

Agradeço desde já !

Comment: Ao invés de postar imagens, poste o seu código. Somente assim poderemos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Talvez, [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124234/20615) também possa lhe ajudar, mesmo não sendo com o materialize

Comment: Oi @randrade,obrigado pela ajuda,li todo esse tópico com calma e não achei a solução, mesmo sendo o mesmo problema :/,evitei colocar o código todo para não ocupar o tempo de vocês.abraços.

Comment: Bom, é justamente o contrário. As imagens complicam o entendimento, até mesmo porque geralmente fazemos um exemplo funcional. Então, fazer isso somente com as imagens é um pouco complicado. Mas, se postar seu código, ficarei feliz em ajudar.

Comment: @Randrade,obrigado,fiz um codepen para analisares melhor:
http://codepen.io/saidmrn/pen/JRxQva

Comment: @bacco exatamente o mesmo problema,segui a solução apresentada pela resposta porém continua com problemas.
Quando ponho o width do box para 30%,fica correto:
http://i.imgur.com/vEZ0Onq.png   porém fica pequena a tabela.
Quando ponho 40% de width,o problema volta a persistir
http://i.imgur.com/VQNJ1aQ.png

Comment: @edit Consegui de uma certa forma fazer com que ocupem espaço com o Mansory,porém ele não ocupa toda a área do lado direito    http://i.imgur.com/eySPl8s.png   Se eu aumento o width,ele passa a colocar um embaixo do outro,como eu poderia fazer com que ele ocupasse toda a area vazia ao lado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MANSORY LAYOUT**
O que você está querendo criar é um **mosaico**, conhecido em inglês como ***Mansory Layout***, você pode até se preferir usar a biblioteca **[Mansory.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**.

Considerando o uso de frameworks eu sugeriria o uso do **[BOOTSTRAP4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/)** ou **[BULMA](http://bulma.io/documentation/grid/tiles/)**, ambos possuem suas grid baseadas em flexbox, inclusive o *Bulma* possui classes desenvolvidas justamente pra criação de *Mansory Layouts*... caso seja muito prejudicial a seu projeto modificar tanto a estrutura e tudo mais, você mesmo pode criar seu mansory usando **[FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**.

Fiz um **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/viniciusColares/08por9o2/1/)** com um exemplo da solução usando *flexbox css*.

**BOOTSTRAP**
Se ainda assim você preferir usar o **Bootstrap 3**, aconselho fortemente o agrupamento de cada linha de tabelas dentro de uma tag `<div class="row"></div>`, é a maneira mais simples de solucionar seu problema, apesar de não ser a solução perfeita.

Comment: Oi Vinicius,obrigado pela ajuda,foi muito útil para entender sobre flexbox.

Comment: Porém,como eu poderia separar as colunas se elas são criadas dinamicamente ?,Você tem alguma idéia ?,caso o contrário o jeito será utilizar bootstrap mesmo :),abraços!

Comment: Se a questão for apenas separar as colunas, vc pode mapear quantas tabelas seriam no total, e dividir pela quantidade de colunas que vc preferir